# How do You Organize Big Data in your Database?

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata

I have some database with big data inside it, now I am thinking how to organize them to be more scallable.

some point as my consideration is :

1. Security
2. Performance
3. Cost

Generally answer is welcome, because I am still didn't expected all of my problem or possibility risk will happen, it's will help me if you can give me some suggestion.

Comment: from what i understood you have a big traffic in your database, plus a lot of data to handle, and I assume you are using only a regular machine laptop, or an ordinary PC, if that is the case you need to buy a strongest machine that is capable of handling all your data. and as a matter of optimizing you can use the views and pagination (in your application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a full answer to your question we will need more information on how big the data is, how complex, what your use cases are (ie. do you do many joins on multiple tables or are they mostly on a single table?). In any case, here are some good pointers that would help you get on your way.

1. If you are expecting your data to grow rapidly, I would recommend that you look at a cloud based database solution rather than invest on physical hardware that would need replacing every so often. Cloud based solutions provide you more freedom to scale your database both vertically and horizontally. There are specialized cloud database technologies such as Amazon [RedShift](http://aws.amazon.com/redshift%E2%80%8E) and recently introduced [Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) which can be configured easily as your requirements grow.
2. For performance improvement within the database you can always look at indexes and changes in structures. Use the [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) syntax in MySQL to analyze your queries and see if the queries use temporary tables or data scans which will slow things down. Adding indexes to columns that you use for filtering or merging data increases performance drastically.
3. In data warehouses, you can also [denormalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and pre-join tables to improve performance. Although this will drastically increase your storage use, due to the fact that you are only working with one data table increases the performance as the time taken to do the join over and over again is taken off the equation.
4. If you are looking at massive datasets that will grow in structure and complexity, there are other non relational database technologies such as [noSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) based [Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/), [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), etc. Moving into these environments may need you to rewrite most of your application, but is something that you should consider before you find yourself in the need for such things when the data has grown too big.

**EDIT**

5. Privacy and data security as pointed out below by @Saïd Tahali in the comments. If you can't host your data outside due to legal or security reasons, you will need to invest on your own hardware that will address all of the above in-house.

Comment: this is also a valid option, even though and in my own point of view i prefer to own the machine that i'm running my service on, especially when the type of data has some sort of privacy and has 0% tolerance of leaking at any condition, i'm pointing here at the "Internet" as whole, a physical server has the advantage on this side, you can run it without an external network, you'll be able to use exactly what you need, in another hand, and as you said, that would cost more.

Comment: @rasika thanks for answer , you give me some light now, about how much detail, complex my big data is still not explained, because i just prepare for that possibility risk and trouble.